# Where is the mapping between SElinux source and target contexts

Tags: security, selinux

I am learning about SELinux and have a question:

There doesn't appear to be a direct correlation between the fields of the source and the target.  For example Apache may run with Type `httpd_t` and the files under /var/www/html/ may have type label set to `httpd_sys_content_t`.  These "labels" appear to be just human readable strings unless I am wrong.

So where is the mapping?  How does the system know which target contexts are allowed to be accessed by processes with any specific source context?

`semanage fcontext -a` Will set a custom file context policy which can then be attached to matching files with `restorecon`, but this does not tell me what Type should be used.

What is the "purpose" of the User, Role, and Level fields?  Which fields have to match for an action to be allowed?

On a related note: How does a process get labeled with a specific source context?

Comment: The mapping is under /etc/selinux. See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/selinux.8.html for starters. Red Hat's documentation is fairly useful, try https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html-single/using_selinux/index. The Arch Wiki is also a good candidate for readable documentation: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/SELinux.

Answer (score 1):

The fields are explained here [Contexts](https://selinuxproject.org/page/Guide/Contexts)

However, for average users that don't use [MLS](https://selinuxproject.org/page/NB_MLS) which is most of us, are only concerned with type enforcements (`httpd_t`).

> SELinux contexts have several fields: user, role, type, and security level. The SELinux type information is perhaps the most important when it comes to the SELinux policy, as the most common policy rule which defines the allowed interactions between processes and system resources uses SELinux types and not the full SELinux context. SELinux types end with _t. For example, the type name for the web server is httpd_t. The type context for files and directories normally found in /var/www/html/ is httpd_sys_content_t. The type contexts for files and directories normally found in /tmp and /var/tmp/ is tmp_t. The type context for web server ports is http_port_t.

- [[3](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/using_selinux/getting-started-with-selinux_using-selinux)]

You can consider `httpd_sys_content_t` a sub file-context type of `httpd_t`, its defined in [file-contexts](https://github.com/SELinuxProject/refpolicy/blob/d6b44b9c4f1f313a848990443acb36db0cc8608a/policy/modules/services/apache.fc#L193).

In general I'd recommend as a quick lookup to search code on the [refpolicy repo](https://github.com/SELinuxProject/refpolicy) for info on how builtin-types are defined.
Its one of the quickest ways to get answers imo.

Next to using

`seinfo --all|grep httpd_sys_content_t`

or

`sesearch -t httpd_t -A`

or

`sesearch -s httpd_t -A`

or

`semanage fcontext -l | grep httpd_sys_content_t`

Even better, grab the sources for the policy of your distro and grep the source-tree for that type to get more accurate info that applies to your distros revision of the policy.

The macros can be a little intimidating when they appear in refpolicy sources, but you can search for their definition as well.